# How to debug play2 in idea?

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, playframework-2.0

I found some articles on the internet and some discussions on google group, but they don't work any more.

How to do it with the latest play2-RC3 ?

Answer (score 3):

You can start the play server in debug mode from console [[docs]](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/PlayConsole), and should be able attach a debugger instance from Idea given that you know the port debugger is listening on.

I haven't use Idea so not sure if it is doable or not. It is fairly easy from netbeans. I suspect, it should be similar from Idea.

EDIT: They have also [posted this in their customization guide](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/IDE) for IDEs.

Answer (score 2):

Debugging Play 2.x is very easy with IntelliJ IDEA 12.x, here are the steps you have to do:

**Step 1.** Enable the Play Framework Support plugin and the Play 2.0 Support plugin in File > Settings > Plugins.

[image: repo image]

The generic plugin usually comes with IntelliJ but make sure it's enabled. The Play 2.0 Support plugin can be downloaded by clicking `Install Jetbrains plugin...`. Simply locate and install the plugin from the list, the latest working version for 12.x is **v.0.2.49**. (it may prompt that a Scala plugin needs to be installed aswell)

**Step 2.** Create a new Play app if you haven't or use an existing one

**Step 3.** Create a new Debug configuration: Run > Edit configurations...

You can click the `+` icon in the top left corner to add a new configuration. Simply select `Play 2 app` from the list and give the configuration a name. The default options *should* be correct but feel free to change them if necessary. When done, click `Apply` and `Ok`.

**Step 4.** Your toolbar should now have a Run icon and a Debug icon enabled.

[image: play run/debug icon]

Simply click the green arrow to run the Play application. This is the equivalent of doing `play run` from the commandline (except without the commandline).
To debug, click the green bug, next the the arrow. This is the equivalent of doing `play debug` from the commandline.

You will now be able to debug when a breakpoint is encountered.

**Notes:**

- Make sure there is only 1 configuration running at a time because Play doesn't like multiple instances running at the same time.
- If you're having trouble compiling, do a `play clean-all` and `play package` on the commandline, this should resolve most problems. If there are further problems, also try `play idea` from the commandline.
- Make sure the Play configuration is filled in in your settings. You can do this by going to File > Settings > Play Configuration.

A video of these steps can also be found in [this video by James Ward](http://www.jamesward.com/2013/01/23/video-create-and-run-play-framework-apps-in-intellij) (start at around 1:40 min.).

Comment: You don't need "Playframework Support" plugin to debug Play 2.

Comment: The Play support has been moved into the Scala plugin for IDEA.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Run -> DEBUG -> Edit Configurations**

use "Remote" Configuration and set the Port to **9999**